# Springboot [2.1.6.RELEASE] - Disable autocorrect input dates

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, validation

i got a simple problem.
If i sent a body with following date parameters (below) springboot automatically convert it to the 1st of May 1991 and i want to disable it. I would like to throw an exception to tell the client, that is not a valid date. Is that possible?

My sent body:

```
{
  "gender": "MALE",
  "firstname": "XXX",
  "lastname": "XXX",
  "birthday": "1991-04-31"
}
```

My WebRequestController:

```
public @ResponseBody void updateUser (@PathVariable Long userId, @Valid @RequestBody UserUpdateIDTO userDTO) throws UserNotFoundException, ValidationException {
        userService.updateUser(userId, userDTO); // userDTO got the 1st may 1991
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can do validation such as;

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = Deserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = Serializer.class)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date begin_date;
```

It seems like this will not be enough because you not only check format but want to validate. So you better do a deserializer. To do that you need to change the core like this.

```
 public class Deserializer extends JsonDerializer<Date>{

}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-valid-date from here you can check how to validate date and based on that you can throw error as well.

By the way can we see your -> UserUpdateIDTO

Comment: Only don’t use `Date` for a date. That class is poorly deisgned and long outdated and does not represent a date (despite the class name). Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).